# Are these round black 1x1 pieces LEGO?

Tags: piece-information, part-identification

A friend encountered two pieces of plastic in a bulk lot of LEGO she bought and was wandering if they were actually LEGO, a clone/custom brand or something else entirely...
She sent the following pictures:

[image: top view]

[image: side view]

[image]

There are no markings or numbers on the pieces.
They do seem to fit on LEGO studs:

I don't recognize the pieces so I assume they aren't LEGO.
But perhaps someone here can identify them?

Comment: I'm not sure about the one of the left but I think I have the one on the right in one of my sets somewhere, but I can't remember which one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These are Lego parts.

The part on the left is a hose end ([752](http://peeron.com/inv/parts/752)). It is found on the ends of hoses like this:

[image]

The one on the right is [6221](http://brickset.com/parts/design-6221) (Peeron [424](http://peeron.com/inv/parts/424)).

[image: 6221]

This part was most commonly found in older Technic sets as a spacer or crank handle:

[image: fire truck with crank]

Comment: Incidentally, that hose piece has since been redesigned so it does not come apart. The piece on the right has also been used more-recently for other things, mainly a spacer in tank wheel holders, before it was also redesigned.